# How do I make a form field in html with the specified pattern (MM/DD/YYYY) that adds a "/" automatically after two integers are typed

Tags: html, forms, validation, wicket

I currently have:

```
<input type="text" wicket:id="singleDateField" pattern="(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/\\-. ]?(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9])|(?:(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])[\/\\-. ]?30)|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])[\/\\-. ]?31))[\/\\-. ]?(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}"/>
```

But I need the form to add a `/` after two numbers are typed, then add a `/` after another two numbers are typed, and then not allow any further typing after the 4 digit year is typed. I want the formatting to be predetermined so an error message is unnecessary and the user cannot type in a an unacceptable date.

I hope this makes sense I could use the help!

Answer (score 0):

Recently http://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ was trending on GitHub.
I find it really neat! It is pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: nice solution.it helps me with different requirement

Answer (score -1):

You may use function that will be called by "oninput" at each edition. In this function you must add slash after days and months. To prevention of adding characters after years use maxlength in input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
        function AddSlash(input){
            var dataString=input.value; //get input value
            if(dataString[dataString.length-1]=='/')    //slash already is
                    return;

            while(dataString.indexOf('/')!=-1) //remove slash
                dataString=dataString.replace('/', '');
            var newDataString=dataString.substring(0, 2);  //copy days
            if(dataString.length>2) //add slash after days
            {
                newDataString+='/';
                newDataString+=dataString.substring(2, 4);  //copy months
                if(dataString.length>4) //add slash after months
                {
                    newDataString+='/';
                    newDataString+=dataString.substring(4, 8); //copy years
                }
            }

            input.value=newDataString;  //change input text
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="dataInput"
            oninput="AddSlash(this)"
            maxlength="10" 
            pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/)(?:0[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/)(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))\d{4}$|^(?:29(\/)(?:02)\3(?:(?:\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))))$|^(?:0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4\d{4}$" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some explanation when you post an answer is desirable. What did you change and why?